# Is it possible to use a variable when naming an object?

Tags: java, oop

Thanks for reading my question. I apologize if this seems like an easily searchable question, but searching for anything with variable, object, and java turns up anything and everything.

Here is what I would like to do:

```
BankCheck = check(variable int here) = BankCheck(params here);
```

So that I can create check1000, then check1001, check1002 and so on.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Here is what I used:

`ArrayList<Check> check = new ArrayList<Check>();`

And the this to add each new object to the array.

`check.add(checkNum, new Check(details, amount));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not, that's not possible but you have two options

1.- Create and array to hold a variable number of checks:

```
BankCheck[] checks = new BankCheck[100];
```

That will let you store 100 checks.  You can also use a list:

```
List<BankCheck> checks = new ArrayList<BankCheck>();
```

Which works almost the same, except you don't have a fixed number of checks.

2.- The other option is to create an small program to create this for you and then you just copy paste the output:

```
...
public static void main( String ... args ) {
     for( int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++ ) {
         System.out.printf("BackCheck check%d = new BankCheck();%n");
     }
}
```

But unless you're trying to do something really advanced ( or stupid ) you really will use option #1 most of the times.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

Usually this is solved using arrays. so instead of

```
check101 , check102 , check103
```

you will have

```
check[0] , check[1] , check[2]
```

etc

If the numbers are not consecutive and not known ahead of time one can also use a hashtable

Comment: That would require having a fixed number of possible objects that could be created, right? So for example if check.length = 100, there will only be 100 possible objects until there is an error?

Comment: As far as I understand your question, that is correct. If the number is not ahead of time and they are not consecutive you can also use a hash table

Answer (score 2):

In this case you probably want to use an Array.

```
BankCheck[] check = new BankCheck[100]; //100 objects
```

Then

```
check[0]
```

is the first object etc.

Alternatively, you may use a map if the check numbers are important.

```
Map<Integer, BankCheck> check = new HashMap<Integer, BankCheck>();
```

Then:

```
check.put(1008, ABankCheckObject);
```

will put the check 1008 in that location and can be accessed by:

```
check.get(1008);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices here.

The first option, which I believe correct for your situation, is to declare an array and iterate through it:

```
final int checkCount = 10000;  // Actual count to be filled in by you.  My guess is 10k.
BankCheck[] checks = new BankCheck[checkCount];

for (int i = 0; i < checks.length; ++i) {
    // It's not clear from your question exactly what should go here, but here is a guess.
    checks[i] = check(params);  
}
```

The second option is to code-gen the code if you really need to have a few thousand variables with different names.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to have a fixed upper limit, use the ArrayList class, which can expand as necessary.

Comment: `ArrayList<Check> check = new ArrayList<Check>();` <br> `check.add(checkNum, new Check(this, checkNum, details, amount));`